# Unable to compile code calling static functions on different classes

Tags: c++, templates, static

Let's suppose I have two classes (actually more, but only 2 in my MCVE) defining two static functions with exactly the same name:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void doSomething() {};
    static void doSomethingElse() {};
};

class B
{
public:
    static void doSomething() {};
    static void doSomethingElse() {};
};
```

I want to call one of those functions for all available classes. So I created a helper function:

```
template<class Helper> static void ApplyToAllTypes( Helper& helper )
{
    helper.apply<A>();
    helper.apply<B>();
}
```

Then I do this to call `doSomething` on all classes:

```
class doSomethingHelper
{
public:
    template<class T> static void apply()
    {
        T::doSomething();
    }
};

void doSomethingToAll()
{
    doSomethingHelper helper;
    ApplyToAllTypes<doSomethingHelper>( helper );
}
```

And this to call `doSomethingElse` on all classes:

```
class doSomethingElseHelper
{
public:
    template<class T> static void apply()
    {
        T::doSomethingElse();
    }
};

void doSomethingElseToAll()
{
    doSomethingElseHelper helper;
    ApplyToAllTypes<doSomethingElseHelper>( helper );
}
```

It works fine when compiled with MSVC, but when I try to compile this with g++, it complains:

```
In static member function 'static void ApplyToAllTypes()':
 error: expected '(' before '>' token
         helper.apply<A>();
```

Is that really invalid? Should the sytax be fixed in any way or do I need to find an alternative (then proposed alternative would be appreciated)?

Comment: The standard compliant way will be to use: `helper.template apply<A>();`. Apparently, VS allows non-standard constructs.

Comment: @RSahu: Yes, saw that on the other post you linked to. Never saw this syntax before (mI'm mostly a VS user). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
helper.template apply<A>();
```

Visual Studio accepts this (wrong) syntax, though.

Comment: Thanks...first time I see this syntax!